# How to display characters like ë and Ãª in Android Textview?

Tags: android, utf-8, textview

I have a text file in my assets folder in which there are some texts in German and Chinese.  I used this code for reading the file:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;

    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("name.json.txt");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return json;
}
```

But when displaying in my TextView, it is displayed as question marks inside a diamond. What is wrong with my code? Somebody please help.

Comment: is your file correctly saved in UTF-8 ?

Comment: You are storing it in a byte array. I think the characters that are displayed wrong do not fit in a byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to the fact that your file is encoded in a different **charset**, for example *ANSI* by default when using MS Notepad. You may try with a different charset to get expected results.

```
json = new String(buffer, "ISO8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
try {
File fileDir = new File("name.json.txt");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

String str = null;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

        in.close();
} 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```